# Get parameters from generic functions' declaration - TypeScript 3.3

Tags: typescript, generics, parameters, keyof

I don't know how to get type of parameters of functions which are declared in interface. I need to have proper type checking of them.. Probably I need to use: Parameters class from TypeScript version: 3.3: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.3.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1471-L1474 but I don't know how to use it.

```
interface MyFunctions {
    FIRST_FUNCTION: () => void;
    SECOND_FUNCTION: (string, number) => void;
}

class Params<Functions> {
    private functions: Map<keyof Functions, Set<Functions[keyof Functions]>> = new Map();

    // some other functions...

    public boom<K extends keyof Functions>(func: K, ...args: ???? /* here I don't know how to define type*/ ) {
        this.functions.get(func)(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please edit this question to be a [mcve]?  The interface `MyFunctions` is [not defined correctly](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-dont-i-get-type-checking-for-number--string-or-t--t).  The implementation of `boom()` seems to be trying to call a `Set` as if it were a function, and is passing it an array `args` instead of what I assume is meant to be a spread.  None of these issues have much to do with your question, so it would be nice if you'd clean them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd solve your issue, noting that I had to clean up a lot of stuff and make guesses about what you're doing:

```
interface MyFunctions {
  FIRST_FUNCTION: () => void;
  SECOND_FUNCTION: (x: string, y: number) => void; // FIXED
}

// constrain Functions to a type holding only function properties
class Params<Functions extends Record<keyof Functions, (...args: any[]) => any>> {

  private functions: Map<keyof Functions, Set<Functions[keyof Functions]>> = new Map();

  // use Parameters as requested
  public boom<K extends keyof Functions>(func: K, ...args: Parameters<Functions[K]>) {
    // assert that it returns a set of the right kind of function
    const funcSet = (this.functions.get(func) || new Set()) as Set<Functions[K]>;

    // okay, and remember to use spread
    funcSet.forEach(f => f(...args));
  }
}

new Params<{a: string}>(); // error, string is not a function

new Params<MyFunctions>().boom("FIRST_FUNCTION"); // okay
new Params<MyFunctions>().boom("SECOND_FUNCTION", "a", 1); // okay
```

The parts pertaining to your question:

- I [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) the generic `Functions` type to `Record<keyof Functions, (...args: any[]) => any>` so that the compiler knows that all properties of `Functions` must be functions.  This will prevent you from calling `new Params<{a: string}>()`.
- I have typed the `args` rest parameter as `Parameters<Functions[K]>`, where `Functions[K]` [looks up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) the property of `Functions` with the key `K`.  Since, due to the generic constraint, the compiler knows that `Functions[K]` must be a function type, it is happy to allow you to pass it to `Parameters<>` and return a tuple of the parameters.

I re-wrote the implementation of `boom()` to make more sense to me.  I needed to do a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler that what comes out of `this.functions.get(func)` is actually a set of `Functions[typeof func]` as opposed to a set of the wider `Functions[keyof Functions]`.  And I called each function element of the acquired `Set`, using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) on the arguments.  If these assumptions are wrong, hopefully they'll still steer you in a useful direction.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you so much!